Supress output of library loading information in R when using Jupyter Lab
I am using the following code to load two R packages in Jupyter Lab:

I want to supress any output from this code cell. I tried invisible(library(sommer)), which did not work. In addition, invisible() is not what I want here since I want to supress all output of this cell, but invisible() just supresses output of the line it encloses.
Is there a way to supress output of a code cell entirely when using R, not Python, in Jupyter Lab/Notebook?

Yes, I wish to find a cell-level suppresion. Additionally, invisible(library(sommer)) did not suppress the library loading information. It seems that it supresses only direct function output, but not things like messages.

Oops. I'll delete my comment. I hadn't cleared the kernel and so I thought that was working for my example (different package than yours anyway) based on here.

I don't have access to Jupyter, but suppressPackageStartupMessages({library(lme4)}) works for me.  I would expect it to work for you.

I'm not seeing that work for me in Jupyter with the irkernel, @Limey.

Work-around of sorts: Cell-Level Clearing After-the-Fact
Based on here and here that involve IRdisplay's clear_output function that was added in 2021, here is a step-by-step:
Add a cell in the top of your notebook that runs the following:
library(IRdisplay)

Then for your cell that is loading the two R packages, add a line at the end to clear the output using IRdisplay's clear_output function, setting waiting to FALSE:
library(sommer)
library(lme4)
clear_output(wait = FALSE) # THIS WILL CLEAR OUT ALL OUTPUT AFTER RUNNING THE CODE ABOVE


Details:
From what I see here and failed attempts with chaining commands with ;, I don't see a way that is multi-line for suppressing/capturing in the IRkernel; however, you can clear it out right after.
Has the advantage over invisible()/invisible(capture.output()) use in that it will ultimately remove the output and works for multiline code cells without requiring to wrap each and every line in invisible() from irkernel issue 'Suppressing verbose output'.
